# Is a promise resolved when I add .catch to it?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am new to typescript / javascript, so I don't know much about promises. Here is my use-case: I am creating three different promises inside my cloud-function and then returning it with `Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).` Each of these promises are created inside a function with "return Promise...".

My question is, when I add ".catch" inside these functions, will `Promise.all` still work?. Does it make any difference returning `someServiceThatCreatesPromise()` with and without `.catch()`?

### Code

```
export async function myCloudFirestoreFunction() {
   try  {
        const myFirstPromise = createFirstPromise()
        const mySecondPromise = createSecondPromise()
        const thirdPromise = createThirdPromise()

        return Promise.all([
          myFirstPromise,
          mySecondPromise,
          myThirdPromise
       ]);
   } catch (err) {
       functions.logger.err(`Something bad happened, See: ${(err as Error).message}`
   }
}

// Difference with and without `.catch`?
function createFirstPromise() {
   return someServiceThatCreatesPromise().catch((err) => { // LOGGING });
}

// Difference with and without `.catch`?
function createSecondPromise() {
   return someServiceThatCreatesPromise().catch((err) => { // LOGGING });
}

// Difference with and without `.catch`?
function createThirdPromise() {
   return someServiceThatCreatesPromise().catch((err) => { // LOGGING });
}
```

Comment: The happy path will work exactly the same way as without the catches. But understand, when triggered by a rejection `.catch` returns a *new* [resolved] Promise with whatever value you return from the handler. If all you're doing is logging, you're going to get an implicit `undefined`. You'll either need to return a sensible value in your catch handler if possible or else account for the possibility one or more of the array elements are `undefined` in your `Promise.all` handler (like the code that calls `myCloudFirestoreFunction`).

Comment: @JaredSmith So If I am not interested in the actual return values of "Promise.all", there is no difference between with and without `.catch`?

Comment: Correct! If you're just trying to log errors and avoid an unhandledPromiseRejection error, you're done.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, is that right now `myCloudFirestoreFunction` will be considered successful even if one of those promises fail, so if that's not what you want, you should re-throw those errors and catch them appropriately inside `myCloudFirestoreFunction`. Otherwise, that `try/catch`, given the snippet above, doesn't do anything since those errors are getting caught/handled inside each individual function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `.catch` inside `createNPromise` won't affect anything assuming all your `Promise`s resolve and do not reject.

However, if one of the `Promise`s rejects and you catch it within the `.catch` method, then it won't work as you're expecting unless you re-throw that error and catch it again inside the `try/catch` in your `myCloudFirestoreFunction` function.

```js
async function myCloudFirestoreFunction() {
  try {
    const result = await Promise.all([
      createFirstPromise(),
      createSecondPromise()
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });
  }
}

function createFirstPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("Oof").catch((e) => {
    // do work, e.g. log, then
    // pass the error forward so that it can be caught
    // inside the caller
    throw e;
  });
}

function createSecondPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve("value");
}

myCloudFirestoreFunction();
```

Alternatively, you just `catch` errors inside the caller (`myCloudFirestoreFunction`) instead of catching them separately.

```js
async function myCloudFirestoreFunction() {
  const result = await Promise.all([
    createFirstPromise(),
    createSecondPromise()
  ]).catch((err) => console.log({ err }));
}

function createFirstPromise() {
  return Promise.reject("Oof");
}

function createSecondPromise() {
  return Promise.resolve("value");
}

myCloudFirestoreFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

> when I add ".catch" inside these functions, will Promise.all still work?

Calling `catch()` on a promise does not in any way change the way the original promise works.  It is just attaching a callback that gets invoked when the first promise becomes rejected, and also returning another promise that resolves after the original promise is fulfilled or rejected.

> Does it make any difference returning someServiceThatCreatesPromise() with and without .catch()?

It would not make any difference to the code that depends on the returned promise.  Both the original promise and the one returned by `catch()` will tell downstream code when the original work is done by becoming fulfilled.

I suggest reading comprehensive documentation on promises, for example:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

There is a diagram in there that you can follow to understand what happens at each turn.  Also in that document, you will read:

> Processing continues to the next link of the chain even when a .then() lacks a callback function that returns a Promise object. Therefore, a chain can safely omit every rejection callback function until the final .catch().